# Restlet - How to get cookies from a GET request

Tags: java, rest, cookies, httpresponse, restlet

I'm making a get request using the Restlet api in a java application with this code:

```
// returns a Representation object
new ClientResponse("http://example.com/page").get();
```

I want to see the cookies which are sent in response to the get request.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create the ClientResource object, then get its representation, then the cookies:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://example.com/page");
Representation result = cr.get();
Series<Cookie> cookies = cr.getCookies();
```